# Repeat element in items list in Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have this piece of code which contains items in some layout. I want to repeat this item (`firstRowButtons`) for a `MaxNumber` of times.

```
 items: [
     // for(i = 0; i < MaxNumber; i++)
     {
         xtype: 'firstRowButtons'
     },
     {

         margin: '10 50 10 50',
         padding: '10 20 10 20',
         xtype: 'textfield',
         name: 'Name',
         fieldLabel: 'Survey Name',
         maxLength: 100,
         allowBlank: false,
         disabled: true
     },
     {

         margin: '10 50 10 50',
         padding: '10 20 10 20',
         xtype: 'combo',
         fieldLabel: 'Number of Questions',
         name: 'NofQuestions',
         queryMode: 'local',
         store: ['1', '2', '3'],
         displayField: 'noOfQuestions',
         autoSelect: true,
         forceSelection: true,
         disabled: true,
     },
 ]
 }, {

     padding: '10 10 10 10',
     xtype: 'secondRowButtons'
 },
```

I know that loop cannot be used in an array. The comment is just to show the logic and to point out which element of array I want to repeat.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a function which will return an items array and you can apply custom logic while building the array. Just make sure you call the function with proper scope.

```
function buildItems(){
    let items = [];
    let maxNumber = 5;
    for(let i = 0; i < maxNumber; i++) {
        items.push({
            xtype: 'firstRowButtons'
        });
    }
    items.push({
        margin: '10 50 10 50',
        padding: '10 20 10 20',
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'Name',
        fieldLabel: 'Survey Name',
        maxLength: 100,
        allowBlank: false,
        disabled: true
    },
    {
        margin: '10 50 10 50',
        padding: '10 20 10 20',
        xtype: 'combo',
        fieldLabel: 'Number of Questions',
        name: 'NofQuestions',
        queryMode: 'local',
        store: ['1', '2', '3'],
        displayField: 'noOfQuestions',
        autoSelect: true,
        forceSelection: true,
        disabled: true
    });
    return items;
    }

    Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: buildItems()          
    });
```